# Mock Graphql server with multiple stubs in Cypress

Tags: graphql, cypress

**Problem:**
I’m using cypress with angular and apollo graphQl. I’m trying to mock the graph server so I write my tests using custom responses. The issue here is that all graph calls go on a single endpoint and that cypress doesn’t have default full network support yet to distinguish between these calls.

An example scenario would be:

- access /accounts/account123
- when the api is hit two graph calls are sent out - a query getAccountDetails and another one with getVehicles

**Tried:**

1. Using one stub of the graph endpoint per test. Not working as it stubs with the same stub all calls.
2. Changing the app such that the query is appended 'on the go' to the url where I can intercept it in cypress and therefore have a unique url for each query. Not possible to change the app.
3. My only bet seems to be intercepting the XHR call and using this, but I don't seem to be able to get it working Tried all options using XHR outlined here but to no luck (it picks only the stub declared last and uses that for all calls) https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-documentation/issues/122.

The answer from this question uses Fetch and therefore doesn't apply:
[Mock specific graphql request in cypress when running e2e tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59192617/mock-specific-graphql-request-in-cypress-when-running-e2e-tests)

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With cypress 6.0 route and route2 are deprecated, suggesting the use of intercept. As written in the docs (https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Aliasing-individual-GraphQL-requests) you can mock the GraphQL requests in this way:

```
cy.intercept('POST', '/api', (req) => {
            if (req.body.operationName === 'operationName') {
                req.reply({ fixture: 'mockData.json'});
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else hitting this issue, there is a working solution with the new cypress [release](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/releases/tag/v5.1.0) using [cy.route2()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route2.html#Comparison-to-cy-route)

The requests are sent to the server but the responses are stubbed/ altered on return.

---

Later Edit:
Noticed that the code version below doesn't alter the status code. If you need this, I'd recommend the version I left as a comment below.

---

Example code:

```
describe('account details', () => {
  it('should display the account details correctly', () => {
    cy.route2(graphEndpoint, (req) => {
      let body = req.body;
      if (body == getAccountDetailsQuery) {
        req.reply((res) => {
          res.body = getAccountDetailsResponse,
          res.status = 200
        });
      } else if (body == getVehiclesQuery) {
        req.reply((res) => {
          res.body = getVehiclesResponse,
          res.status = 200
        });
      }
    }).as('accountStub');
    cy.visit('/accounts/account123').wait('@accountStub');
  });
});
```

Both your query and response should be in string format.

Comment: A similar solution can be found here also: https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/smart-graphql-stubbing/

Answer (score 0):

This is the cy command I'm using:

```js
import * as hash from 'object-hash';

Cypress.Commands.add('stubRequest', ({ request, response, alias }) => {
  const previousInteceptions = Cypress.config('interceptions');

  const expectedKey = hash(
    JSON.parse(
      JSON.stringify({
        query: request.query,
        variables: request.variables,
      }),
    ),
  );

  if (!(previousInteceptions || {})[expectedKey]) {
    Cypress.config('interceptions', {
      ...(previousInteceptions || {}),
      [expectedKey]: { alias, response },
    });
  }

  cy.intercept('POST', '/api', (req) => {
    const interceptions = Cypress.config('interceptions');

    const receivedKey = hash(
      JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify({
          query: req.body.query,
          variables: { ...req.body.variables },
        }),
      ),
    );

    const match = interceptions[receivedKey];
    if (match) {
      req.alias = match.alias;
      req.reply({ body: match.response });
    }
  });
});
```

With that is posible to stub exact request queries and variables:

```js
import { MUTATION_LOGIN } from 'src/services/Auth';


...
cy.stubRequest({
  request: {
    query: MUTATION_LOGIN,
    variables: {
      loginInput: { email: 'test@user.com', password: 'test@user.com' },
    },
  },
  response: {
    data: {
      login: {
        accessToken: 'Bearer FakeToken',
        user: {
          username: 'Fake Username',
          email: 'test@user.com',
        },
      },
    },
  });
...
```

[`Cypress.config`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config) is what make it possible, it is kind of a global key/val getter/setter in tests which I'm using to store interceptions with expected requests hash and fake responses

This helped me https://www.autoscripts.net/stubbing-in-cypress/
But I'm not sure where the original source is

Comment: You probably want to store request/responses in a fixture file, and they could be used as a contract for testing the API isolated

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can use aliases as already suggested in Answer by @Luis above like this. This is given in documentation too. Only thing you need to use here is multiple aliases as you have multiple calls and have to manage the sequence between them . Please correct me if i understood you question in other way ??

```
cy.route({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'abc/*',
  status: 200.
  response: {whatever response is needed in mock }
}).as('mockAPI')

// HERE YOU SHOULD WAIT till the mockAPI is resolved. 
cy.wait('@mockAPI')
```

Comment: In the example you described, the response would kick in for both Graph queries (getAccountDetail & getVehicles - in my example above) that need different stubs. Please let me know if the title or description are misleading so I can adjust them

Comment: may be you can provide more details on number of API you are hitting. lil bit of API flows happening will help to understand problem better . for example - first your are hitting accounts/account123 XHR and then using some data from that --another 2 XHR responded in parallel ?? is this the behaviour ?

Comment: the flow is like this: I am hitting accounts/account123 which then sends two async queries to the graph server (getAccountDetail & getVehicles). This is just an example, as there can easily be more than two calls chained to graph server for the same api call